# Convert a FileObject into a File

Tags: java, io, apache-commons-vfs

I'm using Apache Commons VFS2 (Virtual File System) to monitor change file in directory. `org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileListener` return `org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject`. How Convert a `org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject` into a `java.io.File`

Comment: this is just an interface. what implementation are you using?

Comment: If you mean FileListener, there are all methods return FileObject

Comment: no. FileObject is an interface. try to figure out what concrete implementation is returned.

Comment: Even if it's an interface, the return type for the functions can be used to get to the destination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fileobject.getURL().getFile()
```

should work. The caveat is that we need to convert it first to a Java URL object, which can then be used to resolve the file.

Comment: This returns me a String not a File

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
new File(fileobject.getName().getPath());
```

Note that a VFS file object does not necessarily references a real File, it can also reference a file within a zip file for example. Depends on the resolver you used to obtain a file object.

Additional references:

1. [[VFS-443] Need an easy way to convert from a FileObject to a File - ASF JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VFS-443).

Comment: i don't think this will work, if the FileObject represents a File in a zip.

Comment: Especially on Windows, since it only return path on volume, and not path on machine.

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject`is an interface. 
My guess is, that you are working with the following implementation [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.local.LocalFile](https://home.apache.org/~elserj/commons/commons-vfs-2.1/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/provider/local/LocalFile.html)

This class offers the method `getLocalFile()`which return an object of the class `java.io.File`

If you are not dealing with a `LocalFile` most of the other implementations offer `doGetInputStream()` which can be used to create a File object

Comment: the `getLocalFile()` is unfortunatly protected (as the javadoc indicates) which makes it unusable.

Comment: api link is dead