# Java apache commons vfs, create new object for each file in the folder

Tags: java, apache, ftp, vfs

I am trying to create an object from a connection to a server. I make the connection etc.

```
//get files within folder
FileObject localFileObject = fsManager.resolveFile("path to folder containing files", options);
FileObject[] childrenFiles = localFileObject.getChildren();

//now I am trying to make a list of file objects, creating a new object for each file in the folder

List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();


for (int i = 0; i < childrenFiles.length; i++) {                

        //here I want to create a new File object with id = i, 
        //and name = childrenFiles[ i ].getName().getBaseName();
        //I was trying to do: new File(id , name) and append this object 
        //to the list each iteration but no success

        }
```

At the end I want to return the list of files back

```
return fileList;
```

Is my List created correct and how do i make a new object each time the loop goes and add to list?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like the exact duplicate of the question ([java - Convert a FileObject into a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484197)), does not it?

Comment: will the array iv created work? my model for file has several fields I need to populate , id and name but i will want more in future. I read over your link.
my constructor for file ispublic File(int id, String name) {
  super();
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  
 }
will your link work to get me data for each required field

Comment: Could you please provide (post) a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?